# How to use MS Sync Framework to filter client-specific data?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Let's say I've got a SQL 2008 database table with lots of records associated with two different customers, Customer A and Customer B.

I would like to build a fat client application that fetches all of the records that are specific to either Customer A *or* Customer B based on the credentials of the requesting user, then stores the fetched records in a temporary local table.

Thinking I might use the MS Sync Framework to accomplish this, I started reading about row filtering when I came across this little chestnut:

> Do not rely on filtering for security.
>   The ability to filter data from the
>   server based on a client or user ID is
>   not a security feature. In other
>   words, this approach cannot be used to
>   prevent one client from reading data
>   that belongs to another client. This
>   type of filtering is useful only for
>   partitioning data and reducing the
>   amount of data that is brought down to
>   the client database.

So, is this telling me that the MS Sync Framework is only a good option when you want to replicate an **entire** table between point A and point B?

Doesn't that seem to be an extremely limiting characteristic of the framework?  Or am I just interpreting this statement incorrectly?  Or is there some other way to use the framework to achieve my purposes?

Ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is only a security warning.

We use filtering extensively in our semi-connected app.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
//helper
void PrepareFilter(string tablename, string filter)
{
  SyncAdapters.Remove(tablename);

  var ab = new SqlSyncAdapterBuilder(this.Connection as SqlConnection);
  ab.TableName = "dbo." + tablename;
  ab.ChangeTrackingType = ChangeTrackingType.SqlServerChangeTracking;
  ab.FilterClause = filter;
  var cpar = new SqlParameter("@filterid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
  cpar.IsNullable = true;
  cpar.Value = DBNull.Value;
  ab.FilterParameters.Add(cpar);

  var nsa = ab.ToSyncAdapter();
  nsa.TableName = tablename;

  SyncAdapters.Add(nsa);
}

// usage
void SetupFooBar()
{
  var tablename = "FooBar";
  var filter = "FooId IN (SELECT BarId FROM dbo.GetAllFooBars(@filterid))";

  PrepareFilter(tablename, filter);
}
```

Comment: Great! I really, really *wanted* this to be something I could safely ignore!

Comment: I'm implementing something similar. What are you using on the client side database? Compact or Express?

Comment: thx for the info. Too bad it's not express. It's giving me a wee bit of trouble.